# Cannot subscript a value of type [[String:Any]] with an index of type 'String' - Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I am converting my code in Swift 3 and I am getting this error on the line:

```
 let dicArray = serviceProvicedListArray?.objectEnumerator().allObjects as? [[String:Any]]
 let count = dicArray.map({ Int($0["lstActType"] as? String ?? "0")! }).first!
```

Exception: `Cannot subscript a value of type [[String:Any]] with an index of type 'String`'

Please let me know where I am going wrong and let me know how I resolve the same.

Also getting error on this line:

```
 let user_id=String(((data as AnyObject).value(forKey: "UserLoginResult") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "UserID") as! Int)


Exception: Optional chain has no effect expression already produced Any?
```

Does not understand where I am going wrong

Error 3:

```
 if(!((self.serviceProvided!.value(forKey: "Weekly")! as AnyObject).isKind(of: NSNull.self))){
                    let resultObject = self.serviceProvided!.value(forKey: "Weekly") as! NSDictionary
                    self.serviceProvicedListArray!.add(resultObject)
                    let resultObjectItems = self.serviceProvicedListArray!.value(forKey: "lstActType")

                    //print(resultObjectItems[0].count)
                    for i in 0..<resultObjectItems[0].count {
                    //for(var i=0; i<resultObjectItems[0].count; i += 1){
                        //let resultObjectItem = resultObjectItems[0][i] as! NSDictionary
                        let resultObjectItem = resultObjectItems[0][i] as AnyObject
                        self.serviceProvicedList!.add(resultObjectItem)
                    }

                    //print(self.serviceProvicedList)
                    self.serviceProvidedTableView.reloadData()
                }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dicArray` is optional so you need to wrap it with `?`(Optional) or `!`(force) and then call map on it.

```
let dicArray = serviceProvicedListArray?.objectEnumerator().allObjects as? [[String:Any]]
let count = dicArray?.map({ Int($0["lstActType"] as? String ?? "0")! }).first!
```

The batter approach is to use `guard` or `if let` and wrapped the `dicArray`.

```
guard let dicArray = serviceProvicedListArray?.objectEnumerator().allObjects as? [[String:Any]] else {
    print("Not array of dictionary")
    return
}
guard let count = dicArray.map({ Int($0["lstActType"] as? String ?? "0")! }).first else {
    return
}
print(count)
```

Or you can add both the `guard let` statement in single `guard` statement like.

```
guard let dicArray = serviceProvicedListArray?.objectEnumerator().allObjects as? [[String:Any]],
      let count = dicArray.map({ Int($0["lstActType"] as? String ?? "0")! }).first else {
    return
}
print(count)
```

**Edit:** The reason you are facing this issue is because may be you are using `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`, if you use swift's native type it will be a lot easy for you to get/access the value.You can get `UserID` like this way.

```
guard let dict = data as? [String:Any],
      let loginDict = dict["UserLoginResult"] as? [String:Any],
      let userId = loginDict["UserID"] as? Int else {
    return
}
let strUserId = String(userId)
```

**Edit:** The problem is you need to tell complier the type of objects `resultObjectItems` array have, so try like this way.

```
if let resultObjectItems = self.serviceProvicedListArray!.value(forKey: "lstActType") as? [[[String:Any]]] {
    for i in 0..<resultObjectItems[0].count {         
        let resultObjectItem = resultObjectItems[0][i] as AnyObject
        self.serviceProvicedList!.add(resultObjectItem)
    }
}
```

Comment: Apprecitae your prompt response !, I have edited my question and facing a query on other line as well can you look at it . ? and suggest

Comment: Thanks for your response it worked for me Swift 3 syntax are confusing when you start , Will require your help in case of any help

Comment: @RaghavChopra Welcome mate :)

Comment: @RaghavChopra Sure will help you, just give me the link here for your new post(question).

Comment: Please see the Edited Answer, How can we rewrite the same code in Swift 3 for Error3 marked in question

Comment: @RaghavChopra For new question you need add new question or edit your question.

Comment: I have Edited my question, Can you please look at it where I am going wrong this line                     'for i in 0..<resultObjectItems[0].count {'
is giving me error.

Comment: @RaghavChopra Check the edited answer. Now if you have any other error you need to add new question here instead of editing this one.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sure In case I have any query will create a new question